# TestCafe: why t.navigateTo(URL) clears out the cookie

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm manually setting the cookie during the test run as the `userRole` is not working for me in my local environment as the client sets the cookie and due to some reasons TestCafe clears it out.

When my first test is ran it kicks out and I set the cookie before the second test. I can see the cookie exists but as I'm already in the login page I need to use `t.navigateTo(URL)` to login to the homepage. When I use it `t.navigateTo(URL)` clears out the cookie and I keep in the login page instead of the homepage.

If I manually enter the URL of my homepage while the test is stopped at a breakpoint I'm successfully able to go to my home page and my test pass if the debug is resumed from this point onwards.

I was hopeful that the `t.navigateTo(URL)` would be just doing the redirect to URL but it seems with the redirect it is clearing out cookies as well. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually figured out. By running the tests with flag `--disable-page-caching` it worked.